# To find data rate using packet rate

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

I am using UDP protocol for a data transmission from a client to server. So the approach what I have taken is, data rate= packet size *packet rate. As an example I am transmitting 5 packets,
so the question what I have is :

Packet rate should be 5 packets divided by the total the taken for the packets to reach.
so here the total time means the time when the first packet reach the
server to the 5th packet.

The calculation I made is packet rate = 5/the time when 5th packet reached server - the 1st packet reached the server)
I am taking the time stamp when each packet reaches the server.

I am not sure whether this is the right way to find packet rate. since i am getting a confusion with the other time factors like transmission time ,latency.

I hope someone could help me in understanding this.

For a reference
this is my output at the server

1st packet arrival time in sec 1634716276.0

2nd packet arrival time in sec 1634716351.0

3rdpacket arrival time in sec 1634716426.0

4th packet arrival time in sec 1634716501.0

5thpacket arrival time in sec 1634716576.0

Answer (score 0):

Data rate is *data per unit time*, so you need to find the *total amount of data sent* and divide it by *the time it took to send it*.

```
total_time = time_of_last_packet - time_of_first_packet
total_data = size_of_packet_1 + size_of_packet_2 + size_of_packet_3 ...
data_rate = total_data / total_time
```

If you measure `total_time` in seconds and `total_data` in bytes, then dividing them gives you bytes/second which is exactly data rate.

Comment: but the calculate that i want to make is based on packet rate.so data rate=packet rate *packet size